# Facebook FQL posts limit issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Currently i am using following FQL query  :-

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select post_id,likes FROM stream WHERE source_id=XXXXXXXX LIMIT 0,10000&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&format=json

I have two Facebook Accounts / pages & able to download data using above API. Able to retrieve posts & post likes count.

But, from last three days, for one Facebook account above FQL query is not working. it is returning message  :-  **"error": "Request failed"** . For other account it is working fine.

For each facebook Account / pages i have generated separate Access Tokens.

But, if i update limit from : -

- Limit 0,50
- Limit 50,100

  then it is working & returning posts from page but not returning all post which i have previously getting from Limit 0,10000

Please help me, if any one have idea about this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: FQL is now deprecated and will be removed by March 2015. So dont use FQL now!

Comment: That's not correct. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/ v2.0 will be available `At least until April 30th 2016.`, and so will be FQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook will cancel queries which take too long or too many resources to execute. In general, I would never use LIMITs which are that high. There's a high probability that they will fail, and you can't really incfuence the query execution "load" other than setting the LIMIT to a reasonable number (which means implementing a paging mechanism).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried paging also as following : - used api v2.0/125561050791398/posts?fields=likes.summary(1),comments.summary(1)  response of above call got required response with paging previous and next. Used url from next , so got response of another 25 records. but, then next from that response got next link. and when i have tried that link then getting  "error": "Request failed". and my facebook page contains almost 250 posts from year 2010. I am not understanding why that error is coming after 50 records navigation. please provide your feedback on this.

Comment: No clue. Post a bug on FB if this persists

Comment: thank you, Could you please let me know, where i need to post this bug to FB ?.  so it will get answer from FB API team